# Fixing fluid margin with fixed width li design

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/DmgeF/1/

The first 20 `<li>`s justify properly, and when the with drops to 960px there are 4 across and 5 down.

However, in the second `<div>` you can see if you remove some of the `<li>`s the last line looks wrong. I know it is doing what the code is saying (to justify), but is there a way to get the last line to align left?

I am getting the list from a PHP loop:

```
$count = $wp_query->found_posts; // TOTAL POSTS
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    while($wp_query->have_posts()) :
        $wp_query->the_post();
        global $post, $product;
        echo '<li>'. $DUMMY_CONTENT . '<li>';
    endwhile;
}
```

The `<li>`s will fluctuate in amount from 0 to 200, so I've already tried adding classes to them and figuring out which would fall in the "gappy" area (not ideal but would've worked).

I'm assuming some math wizard would figure out how to use the `$count` and my illogical class adding to figure out a pattern.

I was hoping to do it via PHP but jQuery is cool too.

## EDIT

I just thought, what if you could add dummy `<li>`s.

```
if($count == '4') { echo '<li></li>'; }
if($count == '6') { echo '<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>'; }
```

Only more efficient.

Comment: Is this what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/DmgeF/3/ ?

Comment: What do you mean "wrong"? For me it looks fine(ff).

Comment: @elclanrs yeah but now you get 6 across, and I'll have to adjust the margin where before it was automatic.

Comment: @sectus it isn't justified on the div with 18 <li>s? Where the last 3 are spaced but I want it to be left aligned.

Comment: I'd just forget about justifying text, you're dealing with block elements, the trick is to use floats, try playing with the example I provided.